# How make the setMultipartConfig work for a dynamic added servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss, servlet-3.0

When I call the `setMultipartConfig` to the dynamic added servlet `request.getParts();` returns an empty collection when it should contain the file uploaded.

JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/{context here}/hello" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="avatar">
      <button>Go</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The servlet:

```
@WebServlet( "/hello" )
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher( "/hello.jsp" ).forward( request, response );
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Here an empty collection even if I do select a file...
        request.getParts();
    }
}
```

The listener to add dynamically

```
@WebListener
public class HelloListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent event ) {
        Dynamic registered = event.getServletContext().addServlet( "hello", HelloServlet.class );
        registered.addMapping( "/hello" );
        registered.setMultipartConfig( getMultiPartConfig() );
    }
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed( ServletContextEvent event ) {}

    private MultipartConfigElement getMultiPartConfig() {
        String location = "";
        long maxFileSize = -1;
        long maxRequestSize = -1;
        int fileSizeThreshold = 0;
        return new MultipartConfigElement(
            location,
            maxFileSize,
            maxRequestSize,
            fileSizeThreshold
        );
    }
}
```

How do I make the multipart config to work with dinamically added servlets?

Using:
JBoss EAP 6.1

Comment: It seems to be the `@WebServlet( "/hello" )` declaration, figured that out right before posting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `@WebServlet( "/hello" )` declaration solves the problem